# Different Users data shown in Azure Portal and App Insights Analytics

Tags: azure, analytics, azure-application-insights

I want to know the total number of Users in the last 7 days, but the result shown in Azure Portal and in the App Insights Analytics app are different:

Azure Portal:

[image]

Analytics:

[image]

The Analytics query is the one generated automatically from Azure, I just added the sum to show the difference. I waited a couple of days to discard a sync issue or something. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right query to get distinct users over 7 days in Analytics would be:

`union pageViews, customEvents
| where timestamp > ago(7d)
| summarize Users = dcount(user_Id)`

If `sum(Users)` is used after `dcount` was applied then it may count the same user twice if that user visited on several days.

So, essentially you may need two Analytics queries - one to display daily chart of the users, another to display overall count. You may achieve this in one query with [hll()](https://docs.loganalytics.io/docs/Language-Reference/Scalar-functions/hll_merge()) that executes partial distinct count that can be merged later.